# Filament set the default domain With related path on subdomain server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I made the filament v3 project and uploaded that project to the subdomain server and subdomain like **https://example.com/pma/sar/filament**.

so where do we set this domain with this **pma/sar/filament** path as the default domain?

Comment: Does this help? https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/configuration#changing-the-path

Comment: I have already used this to redirect the admin penal, but I need to change the default domain to the root path.